# InvalidConstraintException only in designer?

Tags: c#, wpf, designer

I made a small WPF Application. The data is stored in an underlying DBMS and is displayed in datagrids via databinding on DataTables. To retrieve my data I use the fitting tableadapters.

I generated my DataSet and put in the Constraints. I compile it, run it and like it, because it does everything like expected.

My problem is:
Today my Dialog Designer started acting really weird. It starts complaining about unhandled InvalidConstraintException:

> Cannot clear table X because ForeignKeyConstraint FK_X_Y enforces constraints and there are child rows in Y.

Relation x is a "Customer" Table containing:
PKey CustomerID
and 2 other properties

Relation y is a table which displays an 1-y relation between a customer and serial numbers:
PKey SerialNumber
PKey FKey CustomerID (update cascade/delete cascade)

As said above, the application itself is working as intended, the constraint handling works well. When I delete a Customer all of its serial numbers are deleted, too. On edit all references are updated. As said, working as intended.

But when I open up my Designer this exception pops up.

---

Answer (score 0):

You should not expose direct relationship with DBMS from View. View should only define how it looks and then define the datasource in your ViewModel.